# Proving big-O asymptotics for inverted matrices

Tags: complex-analysis, matrices, asymptotics

Suppose $A,B:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ are non-constant and invertible as matrices everywhere, and satisfy that $B$ is an entire holomorphic mapping and $A(z)=B(z)+O(1/z)$ as $|z|\rightarrow\infty$. I.e., there is a constant matrix $C$ such that, for large enough $z$, we have in, e.g., matrix norm $\|A(z)-B(z)\|\leq\|C\|/|z|$.

I want to construct similar asymptotics for $A(z)^{-1}$, i.e., find decaying $f(z)$ such that $A(z)^{-1}=B(z)^{-1}+O(f(z))$. (Intuitively, such an $f$ ought to exist!)

Dropping the $z$'s from the matrices for simplicity, I quite easily found the identity
\begin{align}\|A^{-1}-B^{-1}\|\leq\|A^{-1}\|\|B^{-1}\|\|A-B\|\leq\frac{\|A^{-1}\|\|B^{-1}\|\|C\|}{|z|}.\end{align}

I have no idea how to take this further, since, e.g., the inequality $1\leq\|T^{-1}\|\|T\|$ is of no use in improving the RHS, and I can think of no way of ensuring that $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ are bounded in $z$ and remain non-constant (for $B^{-1}$, thanks to Liouville's theorem).

Any ideas are most welcome! :-)

Comment: By "entire", do you mean "entire holomorphic mappings"?

Comment: In that case you have $A \equiv B$ by Liouville's theorem.

Comment: Is it possible that $\lVert B(z)\rVert$ is small for $\lvert z\rvert$ large?

Comment: Would that not, again by Liouville, imply that $B$ is constant?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean "for all large $\lvert z\rvert$", I meant is it possible for some large $\lvert z\rvert$. Or have you a lower bound $\lVert B(Z)\rVert \geqslant K$ for $\lvert z\rvert > R$?

Comment: In the example I wish to apply this to, $B=V\text{diag}(\exp(\alpha_1z),\ldots,\exp(\alpha_nz))$, where $V$ is constant. So along certain rays, some columns of $B$ become arbitrarily small. Would this force a small norm?

Comment: Wouldn't have worked anyway, the $\lVert B^{-1}\rVert$ would have stayed :(

Comment: Do you agree with me it ought to be possible?

Comment: Thinking about it, not without further restrictions. Consider $B(z) = e^z\cdot I$, and $A$ a small perturbation. $$\frac{1}{e^z + \varepsilon} - \frac{1}{e^z} = \frac{-\varepsilon}{e^z(e^z+\varepsilon)},$$ if $\operatorname{Re} z$ is very small, the magnitude of the difference is approximately $e^{\lvert \operatorname{Re} z\rvert}$.

Comment: Such a pair $A,B$ would not satisfy the asymptotic relation $A(z)=B(z)+O(1/z)$.

Comment: Let $\varepsilon$ depend on $z$, so that $A$ is always invertible, and $\lvert \varepsilon(z)\rvert \approx \lvert z\rvert^{-1}$ for large $\lvert z\rvert$.

Comment: How could such an $A$ be entire? I really don't see this, sorry.

Comment: I thought you dropped the condition that $A$ be entire. If $A$ and $B$ are entire, the bound $$\lVert A(z) - B(z)\rVert \leqslant \frac{C}{\lvert z\rvert}$$ still implies that $A(z) = B(z)$ for all $z$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Will probably try to re-work these ideas with the example I have in mind, I was just hoping to get an over-arching result that would cover several different parts of it.